# Copy entire database from one server to another in .NET

Tags: c#, mysql, .net, database, backup

I am tasked with writing a data transfer utility and one requirement is that I copy an entire MySQL database from one server to another.  The user will simply click a button when they want the database transfer to occur.

I am a little inexperienced with databases, but I worked with them enough to know how to do what I need to do.  What is the quickest way of doing this?

My original idea was do this:

1. Get a list of all tables
2. Foreach table, get all contents of every table and store them in a DataTable in memory
3. Backup all old tables to a CSV file
4. Truncate all old tables
5. Insert the new DataTables into the appropriate database on the appropriate server

Is there a better, more efficient way to do this?

Comment: have you tried searching google for "mysql backup restore" ?

Answer (score 0):

DataTables take up quite a bit of memory. Be careful with this approach, as database size grows, so does the likelyhood that this method will fill up your memory. I would look at using the mysql command line to backup / restore and call those commands from your code.

Using Process.Start Method  =>

```
Process process = new Process();
// Configure the process using the StartInfo properties.
process.StartInfo.FileName = "process.exe";
process.StartInfo.Arguments = "-n";
process.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Maximized;
process.Start();
process.WaitForExit();// Waits here for the process to exit.
```

Comment: so would you recommend doing a mysqldump using cmd.exe?

Comment: You could, or you could also use Process.Start.  It has a WaitForExit command that will block the current thread until the mysqldump completes.

Comment: David: What is the process name for the MySQL command line interface?